# True and 'True' in python condition

Tags: python, syntax, boolean

If:

```
x = 0
b = x==0
```

and I print `b` it would print `'true'`

but if I did:

```
x = 0  
b = x ==3
```

and I printed `b` it would be false.
Instead of it printing false how would I take the boolean value `b` to print what text I wanted?

Let me explain further:

```
bool = all(n > 0 for n in list) 

if bool != 'True':
    print 'a value is not greater than zero'
```

But it prints nothing?

Comment: -1: Please do not use built-in type names (`bool` and `list`) as if they are variable names.  Please use distinctive variable names.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this you mean?

```
x = 0
if x != 3:
    print "x does not equal 3"
```

Comment: While nice, the question morphed; perhaps this is no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

I think perhaps the following will help alleviate some of your confusion:

```
>>> 0==0
True
>>> 'True'
'True'
>>> (0==0) == 'True'
False
>>> (0==0) == True
True
```

Answer (score 4):

An `if` statement as other answers suggest is a possibility (and you could add an `else` clause to print something specific in each case). More direct is an `if/else` *operator*:

```
print('equality' if b else 'diversity')
```

You could also use indexing, since False has the int value 0 and True the int value 1:

```
print(['different', 'the same'][b])
```

but I find that a bit less readable than the `if` variants.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes around `True`:

```
bool = all(n > 0 for n in list) 

if bool != True:
    print 'a value is not greater than zero'
```

or, you can also check for `False`:

```
bool = all(n > 0 for n in list) 

if bool == False:
    print 'a value is not greater than zero'
```

There are several other "shortcut" ways of writing it, but since you're a beginner let's not confuse the subject more than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = 0
>>> if not x == 3: print 'x does not equal 3'
x does not equal 3
```

lte me explain further:

```
>>> list = [-1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> if not all(n > 0 for n in list): print 'a value is not greater than zero'
a value is not greater than zero

# => or shorter ...
>>> if min(list) < 0: print 'a value is not greater than zero'
a value is not greater than zero
```

note that `list` is a builtin and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
>>> list = [1, 2, "value not greater than 0"]
>>> list
[1, 2, "value not greater than 0"]
>>> del list
>>> list
<type 'list'>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = lambda b :("not true","true")[b == 3]
print a(3)
```

will do it for you if you want to put it in a `lambda`.

Comment: this is the first thing i thought of when the OP further explained the problem.

Comment: If the OP is not sure how to properly use boolean variables, the concept of lambdas might be a little advanced.

Comment: It seems to me he understands booleans just fine but was confused between their relationship to strings as well as assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the printing yourself, as everyone suggested here.

It's worthy to note that some languages (e.g. Scala, Ruby, Groovy) have language features that enable you to write:

```
x should be(3)
```

And that will report:

```
0 should be 3 but is not.
```

In Groovy, with [Spock testing framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock), you can write:

```
def "my test":
  when: x = 0
  expect: x == 3
```

And that would output:

Condition not satisfied:

```
x == 3
| |  |
0 |  3
 false
```

I don't think this possibly cleanly in python though.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'True' is not True
True
```

'True' is a string

True is a boolean

They have nothing to do with each other, except coincidentally.  The string value happens to have the same letters as the boolean literal.  But that's just a coincidence.